# Disable pinch to zoom in IE10 while allowing panning [TOUCHSCREEN]

Tags: css, windows-8, internet-explorer-10, multi-touch

I have a scrollable div (that scrolls vertically) with images and text in it. I want to disable the default pinch to zoom on it while maintaining its scrollability.

I'm in IE10 and using a touchscreen. I'm currently using this to target that zooming feature:

-ms-touch-action: pan-y; 
-ms-content-zooming: none;

but the content is still allowed to pinch-to-zoom within that area. If I remove "-ms-touch-action: pan-y;" then it is no longer zoomable, but it is no longer scrollable either.

Alternatively, i was thinking if there is a way to disable multi-touch altogether, that would work just as well since I don't need any multi-touch gestures enabled on this site.

However, the NEC Horizon touch monitor I'm using doesn't have that option in the settings.

Any thoughts? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you post some code, please?

I've found IE's touch inheritance to be wondrously inconsistent. you may have to specify "-ms-touch-action: none;" on the inner elements to prevent the zoom. You may also want to look at the -ms-content-zoom-chaining as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771889(v=vs.85).aspx

MSFT's docs aren't terrible, and worth a run through: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772726(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Got it working.

The fix was to apply this to all elements:

* {
 -ms-touch-action: none;
 -ms-content-zooming: none;
}

and target all elements in the div that is scrollable:

.verticallyScrollableArea * {
 -ms-touch-action: pan-y; 
}

I was thinking this it being inherited by putting the pan-y on the parent div… but it wasn't. The same went for "-ms-touch-action: none;" & "-ms-content-zooming: none;" it must be applied to all elements to disable that feature fully.

Comment: you may want to try the zoom-chaining and scroll-chaining properties out as well. thye worked well for me in a couple of instances (and not at all in others, 'cause, you know, MSFT/IE). it can make for cleaner more maintainable CSS if it works.